# Is it impossible to view and edit T-Sql statements from within Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I am thinking of migrating our database from SQL Server to SQL Azure, but I am a little concerned about the problems with the tooling I've been having.
Specifically, I haven't been able to "design" a T-SQL query directly from VS while working with local Sql Server 2012 Express database. For instance, previously in VS2012 I could go to "Show table data", then display the SQL used to generate the data and then add "order by" clause. But now in VS2012 I don't see a way to show t-sql statements (unless I want to write them from scratch, which I don't).
Thanks for clearing this confusion up for me. Also, can anybody point me to some online documentation describing these changes? I was looking for it but couldn't find anything :-(
Thanks a lot!
Jan

Comment: Have you concerned to use management studio instead - the new version is powered by visual studio 2012 so i do not think you will have any issues while using it?

Comment: I have. But I don't like the idea of having to use two tools in situations where I was able to use just one earlier. If I'm forced to do that, is there a clear communication from Microsoft that VS2012 will not support some features that it did support previously?